# Calculate the hours worked by all employees in a day

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

#### Table vinay_hours

```
id  cico
1   2014-02-20 10:31:00.503
1   2014-02-20 13:00:00.503
1   2014-02-20 15:31:02.503
1   2014-02-20 19:00:02.503
2   2014-02-20 10:00:02.503
2   2014-02-20 18:31:02.503
```

`id` is an employee ID and the records are times when an employee swipes a security card.

#### Expected output

```
EmployeeId  LoginTime                LogOutTime               WorkingHours
1           2014-02-20 10:31:00.503  2014-02-20 13:00:00.503  3
1           2014-02-20 15:31:02.503  2014-02-20 19:00:02.503  4
2           2014-02-20 10:00:02.503  2014-02-20 18:31:02.503  8
```

Answer (score 2):

Having done something like this recently, where the door access system tracks badge swipes, and thus the first swipe and last swipe of the day are effectively logging in and logging out, it's fairly straightforward.

Ultimately you need to group the data by date, then get the min and max times for those dates, at which point you can `DATEDIFF` to the resolution you need.

```
WITH dataWithDates AS (
    SELECT id, cico, CAST(cico AS DATE) as EventDateOnly FROM vinay_hours
),
minMaxTimes AS (
    SELECT id, EventDateOnly, MIN(cico) as LoginTime, MAX(cico) as LogoutTime 
        FROM dataWithDates
        GROUP BY id, EventDateOnly
)
SELECT id, EventDateOnly, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LoginTime, LogoutTime) FROM minMaxTimes
```

This uses common table expressions (CTEs), but could easily be written as a set of nested subqueries. I find CTEs help to break the problem down logically, adding to readability; typically the execution plan is identical).